# Why does the second notification popup before the first notification?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

Is there another way to write this python code where it popups sequentially? For some reason Second Notification is popping up out of order before First Notification :-/

```
import bpy

class WM_OT_myOp(bpy.types.Operator):
    """This is the tooltip"""
    bl_label = "Blender Project Information"
    bl_idname = "wm.myop"
    
    mytext: bpy.props.StringProperty(name= "Enter text", default="")
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text=self.mytext)
    def execute(self, context):  #This runs on click
        return {'FINISHED'}
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_myOp)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WM_OT_myOp)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.wm.myop('INVOKE_DEFAULT',mytext="First Notification?")
    bpy.ops.wm.myop('INVOKE_DEFAULT',mytext="Second Notification?")
```

Updated Question:
Thanks @scurest which cleared my first thought, and both are opening at the same time with the last one on top of the first.  How can I instead have the 2nd notification wait for the first to be clicked?

Comment: Actually they're both open at the same time (try dragging the second one; the first once is revealed underneath it). The most recent one is on top.

Comment: @scurest Haha Thanks!!! Would it take a big modification to wait for the 1st notification click before moving on in code to the 2nd?